# Angular 7 can't access admin folder file

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, .htaccess, angular7

I have done two separate `Angular 7` project `customer portal` & `admin`.

I upload two build to `aws` . Check below image

[image]

My admin build files are in inside admin `folder`.

This is my query when i try to access admin it automatically redirect to `customer portal`

This is my access `url` https://abcd.com/admin

but it redirect to https://abcd.com/

I tried this `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.html [NC,L]    

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /admin/
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ index.html?$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have this line in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.html [NC,L]
```

That redirects everything to `abcd.com/index.html` and then stops evaluating because of the `L` flag.

You need to add something like

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^admin/`

to the first group of conditions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, let me check